# UIActivityViewController post hyperlink

Tags: iphone, facebook, hyperlink, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

help me please, how can I post hyperlink to facebook with UIActivityViewController?

When I am doing like this

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]     initWithActivityItems:@[@"<html><body><br\\>Go here - <a href='http://apple.com'>APPLE</a></body></html>", imageToSave] applicationActivities:nil];
```

I have hyperlink when sharing by e-mail, but on facebook or twitter it's all text.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UIActivityViewController has an interesting API. In your array of activity items, you need to pass in a NSURL object

```
NSString *text = @"<html><body><br\\>Go here - <a href='http://apple.com'>APPLE</a></body></html>";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]     initWithActivityItems:@[text, URL, imageToSave] applicationActivities:nil];
```

You'll probably want to adjust your text string as it'll look pretty poor on twitter/facebook. The URL will be appended to the end of the text in Mail. If that particular text is important you can create a UIActivityItemProvider subclass that is informed of the activityType when the user chooses an activity, and you can format the text differently for Mail vs Social.